# Differentiability of a Poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, poisson-process

While studying the Poisson process, I had a question about whether this process is differentiable in probability and whether it is differentiable in the mean square sense, i.e. $$E\left|\frac{N_{t+h} - N_t}{h} - \frac{dN_{t}}{dt}\right|^2 \rightarrow 0, h \rightarrow 0$$

But I find it difficult to answer this question because I can’t figure out where to start. I understand that $$N_{t+h} - N_t \xrightarrow{d} Poiss(\lambda h)$$
But what can be done next? I will be grateful for any hint.

Comment: The Poisson process is an increasing jump process, so you get the confusing behavior of $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{N_{t+h} - N_t}{h} = 0$ almost surely (fact A), but also that $\mathbb{E}[\frac{N_{t+h} - N_t}{h}] = \lambda$ where $\lambda$ is the parameter of your Poisson process. I don't think a derivative process can necessarily exist in this sense because by (fact A), $dN_t/dt$ would have to be 0. Also, what you've written is the $L_1$ expectation, no?

Comment: @1mdlrjcmed i edited question, i forgot about square in definition of $L^2$ process. Could you provide more details how did you get that $lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{N_{t+h} - N_t}{h} = 0?$

Comment: $P(N_{t+h} - N_t \geq 1) = 1-P(N_{t+h}-N_t) = 0) = 1-e^{-h}$. So on a set of measure $(1-e^{-h})$, $(N_{t+h} - N_t)/h$ is not 0 (is greater than $1/h$, and on a set of volume $e^{-h}$ (which converges to 1,) the difference quotient is 0. Are you trying to relate the Poisson process to a definition of white noise, like there is for Brownian motion? I'm not super familiar with the L2 construction of Brownian motion but the definition of a stochastic integral still works for the Poisson process.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the second moment of that ratio diverges

$$E[N_{[a,b]}^{2}]=\lambda (b-a)(\lambda (b-a)+1),$$
where $N_{[a,b]}$ is the [Poisson counting process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Interpreted_as_a_point_process_on_the_real_line) in an interval $[a,b]$

and so

$$E\left[\frac{N_{[h,t+h]}^{2}}{h^{2}}\right]=\frac{\lambda(\lambda h+1)}{h}\to +\infty.$$

This implies that it cannot converge in $L^{2}$ because we have the contradiction

$$+\infty\leftarrow E[f_{n}^{2}]\leq E[(f_{n}-f)^{2}]+E[f^{2}]<\infty.$$

However, as mentioned in the comments, there is a stochastic calculus for Poisson point processes because their paths are right-continuous increasing and so one can just use the Riemann-Stieltjes integral see Revuz-Yor Chapter XII

[image]

Comment: could you explain what is $N_{[a, b]}$?

Comment: also, how could we conclude that if expectation is not finite, than process has no limit?